# Rounded UIWebView with UIModalPresentationPageSheet over the top leads to corruption

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I've got a UIWebView that has rounded corners applied to it using the following code:

```
self.bodyWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webViewFrame];
self.bodyWebView.backgroundColor     = [UIColor clearColor];
self.bodyWebView.delegate            = self;
self.bodyWebView.scalesPageToFit     = YES;
self.bodyWebView.scrollView.bounces  = YES;
self.bodyWebView.scrollView.delegate = self;
self.bodyWebView.scrollView.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor].CGColor;
self.bodyWebView.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0;
self.bodyWebView.clipsToBounds = YES;
self.bodyWebView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
self.bodyWebView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0,1.0);
self.bodyWebView.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0;
self.bodyWebView.layer.shadowOpacity= 1.0;
self.bodyWebView.layer.opacity = 1.0;
```

What I'm finding is that this correctly draws the UIWebView with rounded corners but what happens is that on iPad when I display a view controller over the top with the following code:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
```

What happens is that on iPad there is colour bleeding from the underlying UIWebView through to the view controller that is shown above the UIWebView.  This can be fixed by removing the clipsToBounds=YES but at that point the UIWebView loses its rounded corners.

I'm wondering whether anyone else has seen this, and whether this can be fixed?